# Saving Card Position in Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I’m trying to pass the position of the card to SlideView Activity where onMenuItemClick was used to bring up the correct information about that specific card. Currently, I’m using getAdapterPosition in onMenuItemClick within my Adapter, but thats resulting in the last element drawn to screen being saved to my adapterPosition. I understand why it’s giving the last position, but unsure how to set the correct position. Should I try to save and pass the position via showPopupMenu or something else entirely? Below are my Adapter & MainActivity.

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Properties> dogList;
private MyViewHolder holder;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, count;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);

    }
}


public Adapter(Context mContext, List<Properties> dogList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.dogList = dogList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    this.holder=holder;
    Properties dog = dogList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(dog.getName());

    // loading dog cover using Glide library
    Glide.with(mContext).load(dog.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Showing popup menu when tapping on icon
 */
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
    popup.show();
}

/**
 * Click listener for popup menu items
 */
class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_more_info:
                Intent slideStart = new Intent(mContext, SlideViewActivity.class);

                super.getClass();

                int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                slideStart.putExtra("position", adapterPosition);

                slideStart.putExtra("list", (Serializable) dogList);

                mContext.startActivity(slideStart);
                return true;
            default:
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dogList.size();
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Adapter adapter;
private List<Properties> dogList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    initCollapsingToolbar();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    dogList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new Adapter(this, dogList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    prepareCards();

    try {
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.austrailian_shepherd).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Initializing collapsing toolbar
 * Will show and hide the toolbar title on scroll
 */
private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

    // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        boolean isShow = false;
        int scrollRange = -1;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            }
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                isShow = true;
            } else if (isShow) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                isShow = false;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void prepareCards() {
    int librarySize = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles).length;

    for(int i=0;i<librarySize;i++) {
        String dognames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles)[i];
        String doginfo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.info)[i];
        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(dognames.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable", this.getPackageName());

        Properties a = new Properties(dognames, doginfo, imageId);
        dogList.add(a);

    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

/**
 * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
 */
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Converting dp to pixel
 */
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `getAdapterPosition` try using the `getLayoutPosition` which is the absolute position of the item in the list based on the view.

Comment: When changing to **int adapterPosition = holder.getLayoutPosition();** the result is the same - do I have to configure it differently?

Comment: One more solution is to add a reference to the holder in your `MyMenuItemClickListener`, also make that class `public static` to make it a fully qualified class.

Answer (score 1):

Try these modifications :

```
holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow, position);
        }
    });
```

```
private void showPopupMenu(View view, int pos) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener(pos));
    popup.show();
}
```

```
class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    int pos;

    public MyMenuItemClickListener(int pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_more_info:
                Intent slideStart = new Intent(mContext, SlideViewActivity.class);

                super.getClass();

                slideStart.putExtra("position", pos);

                slideStart.putExtra("list", (Serializable) dogList);

                mContext.startActivity(slideStart);
                return true;
            default:
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```